# How to highlight trends in time records? (system errors)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, timestamp, error-logging, data-visualization

I have a list of system error *timestamps*.

I want to graph the time from the timestamps to see if there are any trends -- i.e. approximate times of day when the system often goes down.

**Question:**

Is there a way to graph time data in Excel to highlight trends?

*I'm familiar with graphing data that has obvious X & Y axes. But I'm struggling when it comes to this simple example where I only have a single axis.*

---

```
(the dates can be ignored; just the time is important)

TIME OF ERROR 
--------------
3/26/21 2:37 AM
2/15/21 5:31 AM
1/29/21 12:02 PM
2/3/21 11:10 PM
2/3/21 11:10 PM
3/31/21 3:50 AM
5/11/21 4:59 AM
5/11/21 4:59 AM
3/31/21 3:50 AM
3/23/21 12:22 AM
5/16/21 4:19 AM
4/5/21 6:49 AM
4/15/21 11:29 AM
1/19/21 12:10 PM
3/19/21 1:05 AM
1/13/21 11:42 AM
1/13/21 11:42 AM
1/19/21 12:10 PM
1/13/21 11:58 PM
1/13/21 11:58 PM
1/26/21 12:23 AM
5/16/21 4:19 AM
1/13/21 11:58 PM
3/19/21 1:06 AM
3/19/21 1:05 AM
1/26/21 12:23 AM
4/15/21 11:29 AM
3/23/21 12:22 AM
2/15/21 5:31 AM
1/19/21 12:10 PM
5/16/21 4:19 AM
5/16/21 4:19 AM
4/5/21 6:49 AM
4/15/21 11:29 AM
3/31/21 3:50 AM
5/16/21 4:19 AM
5/11/21 4:59 AM
1/29/21 12:02 PM
```

Comment: "to highlight trends?" I'm not aware of any functionality in Excel which would identify the trend for you. If you suppose any errors happen in the morning, you might extract hour from errors date time and plot that. If there are scripts running at each hour and those might cause errors, you might extract minutes and plot those... Even you can create histograms of your data

Comment: Hi @User1973 ,, check the Edited Part 1 & 2 of my post and I do believe that is what you were looking for,, plz confirm through comments whether is working for you or not !!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you’ve got to extract the times. 
Assuming that you have the timestamps in Column `A`:

- If they are in Excel date/time numeric format (they probably are),
  you can use `=MOD(A1,1)` to get the time component.
- In the unlikely event that the timestamps are in text format,
  use `=TIMEVALUE(A1)`.

Put the above in Column `B`.

#### Approach 1

Put some arbitrary number, e.g., `1`, in Column `C`.

[image: Columns A, B and C]

Then create an X-Y Scatter plot of Columns `B` and `C`:

[image: X-Y Scatter plot of Columns B and C]

This gives a very rough indication of what times of day the events happen. 
Well, it might be more accurate to say
that it shows when the events ***don’t*** happen. 
For example, it appears that there are ***no*** events
between 1 PM and 11 PM. 
It’s hard to see how many dots there are when they are close together.

[Note that the charts in this answer are based on the *entire* dataset
(list of timestamps) posted in the question.]

#### Approach 2

Go somewhere else on the spreadsheet; e.g., Columns `P`, `Q` and `R`. 
Enter the integers 0 through 24 in `P1` through `P25`. 
In `Q1`, enter `=P1/24` and drag/fill down. 
Enter `0` in `R1`. 
In `R2`, enter

```
=COUNTIFS(B$1:B$38, ">" & Q1, B$1:B$38, "<=" & Q2)
```

and drag/fill down. 
This partitions the day into 24 hours
and counts how many events occurred in each hour.

[image: Columns P, Q and R]

Then do a Column chart of Columns `Q` and `R`:

[image: Column chart of Columns Q and R]

This shows how many events occurred in each hour of the day. 
It clarifies that most of your events occur in the morning
(between midnight and about 7 AM),
a cluster around noon (between 11 AM and 1 PM),
and another cluster just before midnight. 
Or, taking a more global look at it: most of the events occur
between 11 PM and 7 AM, and a few occur between 11 AM and 1 PM. 
*All* the events occur within those ten hours.

Obviously you can make this finer or coarser, as per your requirements.

Comment: in both cases how you add TIME value to Y Axis,, and for me the COUNTIF formula returns #VALUE error !!

Answer (score 0):

*This solves the issue:*

[image]

**N.B.** *For better visualization & understanding I've taken only few rows, you may go with all.*

**How it works:**

- Your data in in Col A.
- Enter this in cell B118 `=INT(A118)` & fill down, format is `dd-mm-yyyy`.
- Formula in cell C118  `=A118-B118`, fill down, applied format is `h:mm AM/PM`.
- *Step 2 & 3 are required to split TIME from DATE TIME stamp.*
- Now select C118:C123 & hit INSERT then Chart and draw graph what you need, I think Like graph is best suitable.
- Select Time Axis the Right click, hit Format Axis.
- For BOUNDs set

Maximum `0.222222`

Minimum `1.022222`

- Units

Minor `0.1`

Major `0.02`

- Set Ticks

Major `Inside`.

Minor `Outside`.

*You find now Time axis covers most of Time in Col C.*

[image]

---

**:Edited 1:**

*Another is:*

- Select Date & Time data in col A.
- Plot Stacked Line Chart With Markers.
- Select Value at X & Y axis and Delete them.
- Now add LABEL, you find Date & Time Value.
- Select LABEL then Right Click & hit FORMAT LABELS.
- Set LABLE's position ABOVE and FORMAT CODE `hh:mm AM/PM`.
- Hit ADD button, you find this one shows Time intervals.

[image]

---

---

**:Edited 2:**

check this one, is the most appropriate & showing the trend also.

[image]

**How it works:**

*To create Column chart first then add Line graph you need to do followings:*

- Formula in B127: `=WEEKDAY(A127,2)`.
- Create BIN value in `D127:D132` (generally starts with lowest to highest value, TIME has lowest 2:37 & highest is 12:02, so the BIN Range starts from 2 to 12.
- Formula in E127: `=FREQUENCY(C127:C132,D127:D131)`.
- Now Select `C127:C132` & Insert **C**lustered Column Graph.
- Select the X Axis, Right click & Hit Format Axis.
- *Now Set **B**OUNDS, **U**NITS & **T**ICKS as I've shown above*
- Now select `E127:E132`, **C**opy it then Select Chart then **P**aste Special, ensure that New Series & Column Radio buttons has been selected then finish with Ok.
- Now select Chart, Right click, **C**hange Chart type.
- Select **C**ombo then for Series2 pick **S**tacked Line with Marker.
- finally select **S**econdary Axis for Series 1 and finish with **O**k.

**N.B.**

*You may put other chart elements as per your need as well apply suitable Date & Time format too.*

Comment: "This solves the issue" I can't really see any trends in your charts.

Comment: @MátéJuhász,,, Time interval itself is trend ,, if U are pointing out adding the Trend Line  then BAR graph is required but since OP has only one Value is TIME then the best & only possibility left was the LINE GRAPH,,, thanks for raising the issue with Down Vote,,, plzz post if anything address the issue in better way, will help me & others too !!